# FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance() is Crashing App In Multi-Process App

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-manifest, firebase-crash-reporting

After migrating from Fabric Crashlytics to FirebaseCrashlytics SDK, I'm getting some crashes on another **Process**, not the main one.

When calling `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()` in Activity with another **Process** the App just crashes without generating any single Stack Trace or any Log message even there is no Crash Report in Crashlytics.

Firebase Crashlytics Dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.1'
```

Activity Declaration in Manifests:

```
<activity
        android:name=".view.alarm.AlarmActivity"
        android:process="alarm.process"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        android:showWhenLocked="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
        android:turnScreenOn="true"
        tools:targetApi="o_mr1" />
```

Test Code:

```
 try {
     throw RuntimeException("Test Crash")
  }
 catch (e:Exception){
     FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
  }
```

The First call of `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()` will crash the App.

Comment: You might miss   `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(applicationContext)` before `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()`

Comment: @MD Thanks for the reply. but According to the documentation the explicit initialization of Crashlytics is no longer required if you've upgraded to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.

Comment: It's required if you migrated from fabric to firebase

Comment: @MD But I did not Migrated from Fabric. I have been using Firebase Crashlytics from the very start.

Comment: @MD Oh, Yes it does really work fine now If possible can you provide the documentation stated that we need to use `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(applicationContext)` if we Migrated from Fabric or old Crashlytics SDK. Thanks a lot, Sir you can answer it I will accept it.

Comment: I faced the same kind of issue in last week and i read some where in documentation about it. Let me check about documentation link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(applicationContext)
```

before accessing

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()
```

You can check more at [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp)

Comment: i have done this code for `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey("userId", "0123") getting user id to identify which user got crash but I wrote that code in to my Main activity onCreate() and then try ti crash app through `throw RuntimeException("Test Crash") ` this code but not getting any keyon firebase console whats wrong with that?
`